# Does Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection guarantee registration order when resolving IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

Let's assume we have the following code:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo1>();
services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo2>();

var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

foreach (var foo in container.GetService<IEnumerable<IFoo>>())
{
    Console.Write($"{foo.GetType().Name} ");
}
```

Is there a guarantee in Microsoft DI that the output will be `Foo1 Foo2` for all starts?

Comment: I think this is not guaranteed, because the IEnumerable is a sortable property an its fills is in the framework background

Comment: No, it is guaranteed, thanks @steven  for the link.